# Tmux mouse-mode on does not allow to select text with mouse

Tags: configuration, tmux, mouse

I'm using `tmux 2.1` and tried to on mouse mode with

```
set -g mouse on
```

And it works fine, I can switch across `tmux` window splits by clicking the appropriate window. But the downside of this is that I cannot select text with mouse. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the selection just become red when I keep pressing the mouse button and disappear when I release the button. Without mouse mode enabled the "selection with mouse" works completely fine.

Is there some workaround to turn mouse mode on and have the ability to select text?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

If you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> while doing things with the mouse, that overrides the mouse protocol and lets you select/paste.  It's documented in the [xterm manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Mouse-Protocol) for instance, and most terminal emulators copy that behavior.

Notes for OS X: In iTerm, use <kbd>Option</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd>. 
In Terminal.app, use <kbd>Fn</kbd>.

Comment: Note: On iTerm for MacOS use `option` instead of `shift`

Comment: @KNejad This doesn't work on macOS High Sierra inside the Terminal.app. Any ideas?

Comment: @BastianGruber From the comments section of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843650/5922350) I found that on Terminal.app you should use the FN key

Comment: The screenshot shows gnome-terminal, which is one of the "most terminal emulators".  Terminal.app is different (and introduced mouse support only a few years ago).  None of the keys on my keyboard modify its behavior.

Comment: This approach doesn't work well if you have multiple tmux panes. I can select the text, but the selection overlaps terminal lines across all the tmux panes.

Comment: @EddyR. This is where ctrl-b + z comes in handy.

Comment: All of this "on $foo terminal emulator and $bar OS version, use $baz key" are really holding tools like vim and tmux back. Why is this an ongoing problem?

Comment: There are so many great tips in these answers and comments. I suggest expanding
and reading them all. For anyone who may overlook @cfz42's comment for its
terseness, Ctrl-b + z is a default binding described as "Toggle zoom state of
the current pane" in the man page. It's implemented as [`resize-pane
-Z`](https://man.openbsd.org/tmux.1#:~:text=with%20-z%2C%20the%20active%20pane%20is%20toggled%20between%20zoomed%20%28occupying%20the%20whole%20of%20the%20window%29%20and%20unzoomed%20%28its%20normal%20position%20in%20the%20layout%29.)

Comment: This option works very well, but not if you're using tmux, and splitting panes. It will cover the whole area, including trails.

Answer (score 22):

Thomas Dickey's answer is probably what most people are looking for.

To give some more context on the behavior you are observing, when `tmux`'s mouse mode is on it enables text selection within a particular pane. That's the red text highlighting shown in your screenshot. It can be useful when you have split panes and want to only copy text within one.

When you release the mouse button the selected text is copied to `tmux`'s internal clipboard. You can then paste that text using `Ctrl+B ]`.

Unfortunately it does not copy to the system's primary clipboard, so you can't select in `tmux` and then paste into a browser for instance. You can configure that behavior though. See this answer to [How to copy and paste with a mouse with tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318285/11493).

Comment: "clipboard" and "primary" are two types of *selection*

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue where mouse click and drag (`tmux-yank`) stopped working on MacOS, try <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: it appears to work, but curious what does `Cmd+R` do?

Comment: This tip is for Terminal.app - according to the associated item in the "View" menu, Cmd+R toggles "Allow Mouse Reporting".

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works on tmux 3.3a (may work on slightly older version).

```
# Mouse mode
set-option -g mouse on

bind-key    -T root         MouseDrag1Pane       if-shell -F "#{||:#{pane_in_mode},#{mouse_any_flag}}" { send-keys -M } { copy-mode -M }
bind-key    -T root         WheelUpPane          if-shell -F "#{||:#{pane_in_mode},#{mouse_any_flag}}" { send-keys -M } { copy-mode -e }
bind-key    -T copy-mode    WheelUpPane          select-pane \; send-keys -X -N 5 scroll-up
bind-key    -T copy-mode    WheelDownPane        select-pane \; send-keys -X -N 5 scroll-down

bind-key    -T copy-mode    MouseDrag1Pane       select-pane \; send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key    -T copy-mode    MouseDragEnd1Pane    send-keys -X stop-selection
bind-key    -T copy-mode    MouseDown1Pane    send-keys -X clear-selection
```