# How do I enable tmux mouse support?

Tags: tmux, mouse

I have put

```
set -g mouse on 
set -g mouse-select-pane on
```

in my .tmux.conf file and then I open tmux and create a new pane and I cant switch pane with mouse.
is there something else I need to configure?
I am using tmux 2.9 on Mac using zsh.

Comment: you may look at other parameters like  Mouse-mode has been rewritten.  There's now no longer options for:
    - mouse-resize-pane
    - mouse-select-pane
    - mouse-select-window
    - mode-mouse etc  but it should have work with set -g mouse on only I guess

Comment: I have the same issue. I suspect it's a bug with mac.

Comment: I have no insight into this issue. However, it might be beneficial to also add to your question what terminal program you are using; gnome-terminal, rxvt, etc. It's great that you indicated the tmux version, the hardware, and the shell. (With 'Mac', I assume you are running OS X/Mac OS...if not, that info is important too.) I don't *know* that it would matter, but I presume it could be helpful if this is an issue between the human-input-device all the way down to the tmux process.

Comment: Are you using Terminal.app? I don't think it supports the mouse? Does it work with other applications, or in another terminal?

Comment: Check my answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318281/how-to-copy-and-paste-with-a-mouse-with-tmux/318285#318285

Answer (score 30):

Here is a clarification of Mark Volkmann's answer. First make sure that you have `set -g mouse on` in your `.tmux.conf` file, and that you have sourced the file by running `tmux source <whatever config file>`. I have found the other line you have in your config to be unnecessary. Once you have the config file set up, run:

```
$ exit tmux
$ tmux kill-server
$ tmux
```

**NOTE:** In a previous version of this answer I listed Volkmann's answer as "horrible and unreadable". I do not find this to be correct nor do I find it an acceptable way to treat another person. Please accept my apology for being rude and inconsiderate.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. It was fixed after I did the following:

- `exit tmux`
- enter `tmux kill-server`
- enter `tmux` again

Answer (score 8):

On higher version 2.1 >, use :

```
setw -g mouse on
```

Comment: This seems incomplete. Why should you prefer `setw` over `set`?

Comment: `mouse-select-pane` is removed since `2.1` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832199/tmux-set-g-mouse-mode-on-not-scrolling/33336609#33336609

Answer (score 7):

After making the tmux config change, run `tmux source ~/.tmux.conf` for an "on-the-fly" change

Answer (score 6):

```
# Toggle mouse with ^M; then report it's new status
bind-key C-m set-option -g mouse \; display-message 'Mouse #{?mouse,on,off}'
```

Answer (score 3):

To obtain the default behavior, which is equal as <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> keyboard arrows, use:

```
echo "set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'" >> ~/.tmux.conf && tmux kill-server && tmux
```