# How to copy and paste with tmux using left click

Tags: tmux, mouse

I'm using tmux 2.6 and Ubuntu 18.04 with putty. How can I achieve this?

Obs: [How to copy and paste with a mouse with tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318281/how-to-copy-and-paste-with-a-mouse-with-tmux) uses middle button which don't exist in laptops

Answer (score 0):

For basic usage:

1. `prefi-key z` to switch the active pane to full screen.
2. select the text to copy (left click).
3. right click to paste.