# tmux copy and paste not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, raspberry-pi, tmux

I am using `tmux` on a Raspberry Pi Zero W running Raspberry Pi OS. Every part of `tmux` seems to work with the exception of copy and paste. I can enter copy mode using `Ctrl-b [`, but I cannot get anything to highlight using `Ctrl-Space` or `Space`.

I do not have a `~/.tmux.conf` file. `echo $EDITOR` returns a blank line. What might the problem be, and how might I fix it?

Comment: Any fix for this? I think I have a similar issue.

Comment: See if my previous posted answer helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318281/how-to-copy-and-paste-with-a-mouse-with-tmux/318285#318285

Comment: @JSpen I found a solution, I added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix it by adding these two lines to `.tmux.conf`.

```
setw -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection
```

It uses `space` to start selection and `y` to copy.

Comment: I only needed to use the `setw -g mode-keys vi` line to fix space, `y` was already copy (yank).

Comment: and how to paste?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa you can paste using `Ctrl-b` followed by `]`